# Capybara click_button doesn't go to create action

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have a test defined like this:

```
    it "should have allow you to fill out the new form and save a customer" do
        customer = Factory.build(:customer)
        visit new_customer_path
        factory_to_form "customer", customer, ["kf_code", "supported"]
        click_button "customer_submit"
        current_path.should eq(customer_path(Customer.last))
        page.should have_content "created customer"
        page.should have_content customer.long_name
    end
```

its a pretty simple that that sets customer to my customer factory and then fills in the new actions form with the data from that factory (what my factory_to_form macro does) and the clicks the submit button.

My problem is that the submit button never seems to touch the create action, its going to "/customers" and not saving the customer.

The form is a standard `form_for(@customer)` and the button is just `f.submit`, I can't think of any reason why this form would work fine in the browser but not in this test.

Why would capybara not be posting to the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any JavaScript involved? Maybe try using a driver like Webkit.

```
setup do
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end
```